# Mocha- test api with multiple http status

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

I am testing an API **[Singn up a user]**  with multiple possibilities of http response codes. Like

```
1. http status code -200.
```

> Message:"User Added successfull"

```
2. http status code -422
```

> Meaasage:"Input Data Missing"

```
3. http status code -500
```

> Meaasage:"User Added successfull"

```
4. http status code -409
```

> Meaasage:"User Already Exixts"

how could i Test such APi with mocha . Here is My Code

```
describe('mobile/user api ',function(){

it('signup user with username ,email and password only',function(done){
  chai.request(testCaseUrl)
      .post('/v2/mobile/organizers/'+organizerId+'/apps/'+appid+'/attendees/signup')
      .send({'name':'afraz','email':'afrazahmad@gmail.com','password':'newton'})
      .end(function(err,res){

        console.log(res.text.message);
         if(err){
             done(err);
             return;
         }
         //Expecting multiple  response status here
         res.status.should.be.equal(400);
         done(res.text);

        });

});
```

Comment: Just write one test per status code that you want to test. What's so complicated  about this?

Comment: can i do it in a single test case ? I can do in IF-Else but that does't makes sense to me.

Comment: Why would you want it to be a single test? It's kinda against best practices. Unit test should test 1 specific aspect. You have 3 different things to test here: normal user creation, validation fail due to missing fields and validation fail due to duplicated data. Sounds like 3 unit tests.

Comment: @AfrazAhmad I agree with Yury.  Doing it all in a single test case is bad test design, in my opinion. You should have one test per status code. If you want to reuse some of the logic that sets up the part of your request that is the same for all tests, use a `beforeEach` hook. Or of a `beforeEach` hook does not work well, you could write a factory function that creates requests and that you call at the start of each test to create a new request.

Comment: ok Thank you @ Yury Tarabanko,@ Louis

Comment: make it multiple tests